# IF expression in Azure Data Factory

Tags: if-statement, azure-data-factory

I have a JSON file which is being used as a data source.

My issue right now is when I was trying to map the data into a CSV file, I noticed that the column `documentConfigId` has some values which are within an object and some which are not: (example below)

Without

```
"documentConfigId":{
"12345678"
}
```

With

```
"documentConfigId":{
"$ref": "12345678"
}
```

Is there any way that I can create a dynamic content which will use the first mapping solution for rows which do not have the inner reference node, but when it does have it, it should use the second solution.

[image]

This is what it currently shows in Excel when I just use the first mapping solution.

[image]

Comment: I tested and per my experience, I'm afraid we can't do that in Data Factory.

Comment: I did assume so but thought I should see if anyone had a better knowledge about it. Thanks anyway

Comment: You're welcome. We could wait for some days if still with no new reply, may I post it as answer?

Comment: Yes, feel free to post as an answer, if no one posts a solution by tomorrow then i'd mark yours as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested and per my experience, I'm afraid we can't do that in Data Factory.

HTH.